# Invalid or missing account ID google tag mangaer

Tags: shopify, google-tag-manager

i am getting error "Invalid or missing account ID" after installing Google tag manager in my shopify site .

please check these 2 images

[image: error]

[image: account code]

Both account IDs are same . but still getting error . no idea why this is coming and where i am wrong

any help

Comment: You are not wrong, Tag Assistant is wrong. GTM container ids are now allowed to have seven characters, one up from the previous six. Tag Assistant still flags the format as "invalid" (but it isn't).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [It seems I have problems with Google Tag & Google Analytics - what am I doing wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112338/it-seems-i-have-problems-with-google-tag-google-analytics-what-am-i-doing-wr)

Comment: @Trend Snaps.. Unless you are using many (more than 5) codes in GTM, I'd advice against using GTM on Shopify store. Shopify has a better mechanism of using Google Analytics by default.